# Quarkus 2 vs JUnit TestInfo: classloader issue on annotated test

Tags: junit5, quarkus

In order to make some configurations, I'm reading annotations on tests using JUnit `TestInfo`.

However I'm facing a problem on Quarkus 2 since `TestInfo` is loaded with a different classloader than my test, so looking for annotations using `testInfo.getTestMethod()...getAnnotationsByType` does not return anything.

Consider:

```
@QuarkusTest
@MyTestConfig("class")
public class AnnotatedTest {

    @Test
    @MyTestConfig("method")
    void test(TestInfo testInfo) {
        Class<?> declaringClass = testInfo.getTestMethod().orElseThrow().getDeclaringClass();

        System.out.println("declaringClass classloader: " + declaringClass.getClassLoader());
        System.out.println("this classloader: " + this.getClass().getClassLoader());
    }
}
```

This gives (Quarkus 2.1.2.Final):

```
declaringClass classloader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@3b192d32
this classloader: QuarkusClassLoader:Quarkus Runtime ClassLoader: TEST restart no:0@6a9ad3d6
```

On Quarkus 1.13.7 both are:

```
declaringClass classloader: QuarkusClassLoader:Quarkus Base Runtime ClassLoader
this classloader: QuarkusClassLoader:Quarkus Base Runtime ClassLoader
```

As a consequence, this doesn't work:

```
@QuarkusTest
@MyTestConfig("class")
public class AnnotatedTest {

    @Test
    @MyTestConfig("method")
    void testProcessAnnotation(TestInfo testInfo) {
        assertThat(processAnnotation(testInfo, MyTestConfig.class))
                .extracting(MyTestConfig::value).containsExactly("class", "method");
    }

    <T extends Annotation> List<T> processAnnotation(TestInfo testInfo, Class<T> annotationClass) {
        Method m = testInfo.getTestMethod().orElseThrow();
        T[] classAnnotations = m.getDeclaringClass().getAnnotationsByType(annotationClass);
        T[] methodAnnotations = m.getAnnotationsByType(annotationClass);
        return Stream.of(classAnnotations, methodAnnotations)
                .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest to file a bug for this. There are certain limitations (JUnit doesn't provide classloading hooks, so Quarkus has to work around that), but the `TestInfo` case might be solvable.

Comment: Thanks, done: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/19482

Comment: Should be solved in Quarkus 2.3